# Is mod_WSGI replacing what apache is doing and how I can make wsgi work at a specific path only

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am quite new to Apache and WSGI, there are a lot of things confusing me.

After a fresh install of apache2 on ubuntu, I can open this URL to see the default apache page `http://localhost/index.html`, the file is residing in `/var/www/html`. So this is the function that apache server provices, serving http connection.

Here's the current situation:

I've created a simple Django project and install mod_wsgi onto my apache server,and finally I managed to deploy the project to apache and the page iIve created can be accessed correctly.

BUT now when I try to access the index.html i mentioned above, it shows the url mapping cannot be found(yes I do not have this mapping in the django project).Is Django taking over all the path that point to the server?

How can I make the django project only map to a specific path like `http://localhost/Django/[MY URL MAPPING]` and keep other url mapping untouched.

So I can access the static HTML(index.html) by accessing `http://localhost/index.html/` and access my Django project by accessing `http:/localhost/Django/[xxx]`

Is this possible? or I have to use another virtual host at another port?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by mounting Django at a different point:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /Django /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
```

This runs the WSGI application at /Django, and leaves Apache to serve the rest of the files directly.

Comment: You're awesome!